# Need to modify dictionary/array enumeration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, dictionary

I have the following method for my search bar, that searches for the key `exerciseName` in `exerciseArray`.  This is working fine, but it is only adding that key to the `listOfItems` item that i then use to populate the cell's textLabel.  I want it to also have the coresponding `muscleName` as well.  Can anyone show me how?  I think I need to change listOfItems to a dictionary, or have keys?

```
- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.exerciseArray)
    {
        NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
        [searchArray addObject:value];
    }

    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [listOfItems addObject:sTemp];
    }
    searchArray = nil;
}
```

When I log `exerciseArray`:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try 2 things.

1. Populate UITableView with a dictionary instead of an array. Here you can use the dictionary key and value in the cell.
2. You can create a Class, say Workout, with 2 properties - NSString *exercise and NSString *muscle.

For 2nd approach you'll have to modify your code as

```
- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.exerciseArray)
    {
        NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
    //workout alloc init
    workout.exercise = [dictionary objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
    workout.muscle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"muscleName"];

        [searchArray addObject:workout];
    }

     /*See if this is necessary to implement*/
    //for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
    //{
       // NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        //if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            //[listOfItems addObject:sTemp];
    //}
    //searchArray = nil;
}
```

I would suggest you opt for the first approach which is fairly easy.

---

If you go by the 1st approach, you can try out this.

```
- (void) searchTableView {
    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.exerciseArray)
    {
        NSString *exerciseName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];

        NSRange titleResultsRange = [exerciseName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [listOfItems addObject:dictionary];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [listOfItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *stringIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stringIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:stringIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"exerciseName"]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"muscleName"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think the first option is the way to go.  Could you provide some details on how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: But you didn't take into account the method I have in the question.  All I need to do is modify that method to output a dictionary and not an array. I'm not sure what you are doing. Thanks.

Comment: Modified the code. I hope I'm not missing something this time ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just filter `exerciseArray` directly:

```
listOfItems = [exerciseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exerciseName contains [c] %@",searchText]];
```

This will return an array containing only the dictionaries that match.